# PayPal Custom Checkout Form

Tags: php, paypal

I'm new to PayPal and did look around paypal checkout methods but could not find the solution for my project.

My client has asked me to develope below checkout form[image]

For the checkout page, He needs to have paypal hooked up to that custom form. The user needs to checkout on that page and not through paypal (paypal will power and process the payment but that is all). The checkout process would happen only on this page.

Can someone help me what method to use? Is it to use express checkout through PayPal?

Is this something to design this checkout form and send information to PayPal via API?

Is this something to accomplish via PayFlow pro?

Comment: Just to add a little more detail to the answers below - they are referring to `Pro` account because what your client is looking for is credit card processing service/gateway to be able to _collect credit card info on your clients web site_ and send it to some gateway service for processing (and must therefore pass requirements for dong so - e.g. PCI compliance). Hth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Payflow is the solution for this and this article described this very well. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php--net-25397

Answer (score 2):

You could either choose [PayPal Payments PRO](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) available in **US, UK, Canada**

or [Payflow Gateway](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway) available in **US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand**